# Custom plugin menu item does not show up in Kibana deployed using Kubernetes

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, kubernetes, kibana, kibana-6

I have created a custom [kibana plugin](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/tree/master/packages/kbn-plugin-generator) using the instructions from the link below.

When I build and install the generated plugin on a kibana instance deployed using a [pre-built version](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/kibana), the plugin works and the menu item shows up in the kibana UI.

However, when I install the same plugin on a kibana instance deployed using Kubernetes, the menu item does not show up in the kibana UI. The plugin is however found inside the `plugins` directory. Is there any additional configuration to be done for kibana running on Kubernetes?

Installation of the plugin is done with the following command.

```
bin/kibana-plugin install file:///tmp/testplugin-0.0.0.zip
```

I am using kibana version 6.8.2.